# How to use vee validate plugin in vue js 2?

Tags: validation, vuejs2

I want to know how to validate a field in vue js using vee validate plugin

Comment: They have a pretty good documentation (https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate), what's your problem?

Comment: Yes now I understood can I delete this question on stack overflow.

Comment: yup you can delete it

Comment: I don't know how I can't see a ui option can you tell me how to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Vee-validation in many projects. The link http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/ provides good documentation.
However, I am sharing with you a small example from which you can try further and let me know if you need any other help. Hope this helps you :)

```
Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/narwanimonish19/13tggr2x/
```

Comment: I learnt it now i want to know how to delete this question on stackoverflow can you tell me how to delete this question.